# rollapply linear model and store fitted values

Tags: r

I have some time series data and I would like to run "mini" regression models on it but on a rolling basis.

I can run a linear model and plot it using:

```
mod <- lm(Y1 ~ time(data), data = data)
ggplot(data, aes(x = time(data), y = Y1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(rownames(data.frame(mod$fitted.values))),
                y = mod$fitted.values), colour = "blue")
```

Now I want to use the `rollapply` function to apply the linear model. I can use the `roll_lm` function.

```
library(roll)
rolledLinearModel <- roll_lm(
  y = data[, "Y1"],
  x = time(data),
  width = 200
)
```

However, this does not store the fitted values. I am trying to use the `rollapply` function to do so.

```
library(zoo)
lmFunction <- function(x){
  lm(Y1 ~ time(x), data = x)
}


data %>% 
  zoo() %>% 
  rollapply(
    width = 40,
    FUN = lmFunction
    #fill = NA,
    #by = 30,
    #by.column = FALSE,
    #align = "right"
)
```

However, I cannot seem to get it to work. Once I get the results I would like to plot all the (rolling) fitted values as (many different) lines on the plot.

Data:

```
data <- structure(c(46.423225, 46.59877, 46.010689, 46.265236, 45.975586, 
44.685474, 45.480743, 45.312847, 44.950558, 45.454235, 45.683979, 
45.957905, 44.570602, 46.320194, 45.904892, 46.408562, 45.675144, 
46.072777, 46.691334, 46.373215, 46.470417, 45.065445, 44.641296, 
45.330524, 44.323177, 44.181801, 44.641296, 44.199478, 44.349686, 
44.552933, 44.031586, 43.916706, 47.884232, 48.379078, 49.138992, 
49.810566, 50.455616, 50.013802, 49.969612, 49.050632, 49.545479, 
50.38493, 49.775219, 49.465939, 49.412922, 49.377586, 49.943104, 
50.367249, 51.940125, 52.523323, 52.134529, 52.152199, 51.507149, 
50.968124, 51.339252, 51.374603, 51.825249, 52.797256, 52.97398, 
53.159546, 52.850277, 52.947468, 53.804592, 54.84729, 52.761902, 
53.000492, 53.327438, 54.529179, 54.405468, 53.733906, 53.680893, 
53.954819, 53.323814, 53.172737, 52.58617, 52.639492, 53.137177, 
53.066078, 51.404156, 51.706329, 51.937397, 51.466366, 51.688549, 
51.848522, 52.381763, 52.959442, 53.01276, 52.523964, 51.679668, 
51.990719, 51.555241, 51.830746, 52.195129, 52.390652, 52.008492, 
51.750771, 52.097378, 52.666157, 53.057194, 53.341595, 53.483791, 
52.515076, 51.475258, 50.693172, 50.293247, 49.991081, 50.168823, 
50.355453, 50.311031, 50.51543, 50.444328, 50.959793, 51.125267, 
51.644028, 51.259422, 50.463383, 50.919544, 51.098431, 51.474087, 
51.590363, 50.588608, 51.00005, 50.427608, 52.234341, 52.449009, 
52.610001, 51.500927, 51.679802, 52.350624, 52.547401, 53.710148, 
54.121578, 53.754868, 56.295029, 55.874653, 55.677883, 55.320114, 
54.175247, 54.139469, 54.139469, 53.844307, 53.826427, 54.282574, 
54.202076, 54.56879, 54.112637, 54.989174, 54.550903, 53.683315, 
54.41674, 54.479347, 55.311165, 55.498993, 54.604576, 53.397095, 
53.128769, 50.901653, 50.454445, 50.508106, 49.917789, 50.373947, 
51.169979, 51.769249, 51.903408, 50.812214, 50.436554, 50.186123, 
49.694187, 49.747845, 50.257668, 49.676296, 50.284504, 50.758549, 
49.676296, 49.381134, 48.334663, 48.397266, 47.395515, 47.189796, 
47.064575, 47.359734, 47.589401, 46.832859, 46.706779, 47.121067, 
47.742504, 47.742504, 48.012695, 47.94965, 48.120773, 46.895912, 
46.949951, 47.598412, 47.98568, 47.940647, 48.354935, 48.039719, 
49.435692, 49.976078, 49.940052, 49.994087, 50.399372, 50.642544, 
50.021107, 49.624825, 49.093456, 49.273579, 48.706184, 48.652142, 
49.38166, 48.571087, 47.589401, 47.283188, 47.27417, 46.82386, 
45.346828, 46.310501, 46.490631, 46.832859, 44.085945, 43.923824, 
43.923824, 43.464508, 43.662643, 43.356422, 43.806747, 45.26577, 
44.004883, 43.833763, 44.004883, 43.050209, 43.221336, 43.536556, 
43.284374, 43.059219, 43.050209, 42.617908, 42.816051, 43.140274, 
42.942135, 42.825058, 42.419773, 42.221638, 42.527843, 43.203323, 
42.194607, 42.509838, 42.978161, 42.383747, 42.392757, 42.500824, 
42.338715, 42.662945, 41.366032, 42.014492, 42.284679, 42.671947, 
43.175678, 43.130299, 43.529648, 44.391899, 43.575035, 44.07423, 
43.69302, 43.883621, 43.529648, 43.783783, 44.428204, 45.009079, 
44.745869, 44.60973, 43.756557, 44.065147, 44.428204, 44.273903, 
42.522182, 41.941311, 41.551029, 42.041149, 41.995766, 42.168213, 
42.313438, 42.268051, 43.130299, 43.584103, 43.647644, 44.927391, 
44.028839, 44.900166, 44.373741, 44.292057, 43.420738, 42.839863, 
42.966927, 43.38443, 43.856403, 42.694641, 40.979225, 40.643402, 
41.305969, 41.614567, 42.930618, 42.549423, 42.594803, 43.084919, 
43.656719, 42.885235, 42.440498, 42.367893, 43.275513, 43.021385, 
43.130299, 44.700481, 44.455433, 45.562733, 45.408432, 47.02401, 
45.962086, 46.179916, 46.452209, 46.461273, 46.098225, 46.30698, 
46.297901, 45.726559, 46.128777, 47.216648, 46.796124, 46.357327, 
47.362907, 47.390331, 47.326347, 46.878399, 47.143509, 46.512733, 
47.591454, 45.799683, 46.595013, 46.595013, 47.116085, 47.783428, 
47.673729, 49.026688, 49.739738, 47.518318, 48.002823, 47.847416, 
48.450764, 49.191235, 49.428928, 51.147552, 50.004845, 50.416222, 
50.544209, 46.476173, 44.300457, 44.501572, 43.422855, 42.417274, 
44.44672, 44.318741, 43.459419, 43.724533, 44.19989, 43.527405, 
44.163044, 43.895897, 43.4445, 42.965462, 42.652256, 42.993103, 
42.937824, 42.956257, 41.952137, 41.804737, 41.556007, 40.717705, 
41.66655, 40.837463, 40.441341, 40.846676, 40.855885, 41.28886, 
41.316494, 40.036007, 39.999153, 40.662434, 40.109707, 39.612244, 
39.870186, 38.810791, 38.17514, 39.059517, 38.709457, 39.317463, 
39.501705, 38.737087, 39.26218, 39.326668, 39.252972, 38.866058, 
38.64497, 39.041096, 38.737087, 38.820004, 38.875278, 38.727882, 
38.681816, 38.598911, 37.73296, 37.806664, 37.77903, 38.700245, 
38.995029, 38.525215, 38.525215, 37.889572, 37.52108, 37.051262, 
36.867023, 37.769817, 37.539513, 37.134182, 36.94072, 37.428967, 
37.557945, 37.659267, 37.889572, 38.985821, 39.216122, 39.151634, 
39.317463, 39.271393, 38.746304, 38.543636, 38.976608, 39.022667, 
39.022663, 38.176979, 37.805244, 38.269909, 38.539417, 39.905521, 
39.543095, 39.636028, 39.747547, 40.286556, 41.169422, 41.076492, 
42.693531, 42.349682, 41.550449, 42.451904, 42.042999, 41.085785, 
38.632347, 38.400021, 38.706692, 38.93903, 39.106308, 38.976196, 
39.292168, 39.217831, 39.394398, 40.32373, 40.602531, 39.914825, 
40.18433, 39.89624, 39.905521, 39.636028, 39.143475, 39.143475, 
38.67881, 38.520832, 41.476101, 41.903599, 41.448223, 41.243774, 
41.020733, 39.859066, 39.645321, 39.924118, 40.946388, 40.277267, 
40.546772, 40.574654, 40.658291, 40.193626, 38.455772, 38.660225, 
38.102631, 38.204857, 39.273586, 39.440865, 40.221504, 39.812599, 
39.719662, 39.821892, 40.444546, 40.072819, 40.175037, 39.450161, 
39.608143, 39.859066, 40.955681, 40.955681, 41.234474, 41.448223, 
41.262356, 41.336704, 41.40176, 41.141548, 41.582008, 41.619503, 
42.369228, 42.584782, 42.500431, 41.863163, 41.97562, 42.013115, 
42.172424, 42.453575, 42.781593, 42.697239, 42.125572, 40.907253, 
41.197773, 40.9916, 39.820141, 38.573715, 38.358166, 38.348793, 
38.151989, 38.629944, 39.051666, 37.823982, 37.083618, 36.296402, 
35.49044, 35.36861, 34.96563, 33.728573, 34.225269, 35.387352, 
35.818447, 36.821217, 37.299168, 36.746246, 37.02739, 38.386276, 
38.292564, 38.170727, 38.217587, 38.986061, 38.911098, 38.779888, 
38.779888, 37.664661, 37.561581, 37.5522, 37.383514, 38.798634, 
39.023552, 40.110668, 39.820141, 39.63271, 40.663593, 39.229729, 
36.971169, 35.846561, 34.646996, 33.841026, 33.756687, 33.074928, 
32.876083, 32.137501, 32.03334, 31.484144, 31.256889, 30.518316, 
30.215313, 32.014408, 32.099625, 32.156437, 32.307938, 32.270069, 
31.379988, 32.8382, 33.813499, 34.495262, 34.542606, 34.656235, 
34.608887, 34.883484, 35.016052, 35.101273, 35.300117, 35.442154, 
34.400574, 34.135445, 34.561543, 34.921364, 34.665699, 32.913948, 
34.542606, 34.902424, 34.703579, 34.627827, 34.665699, 34.466854, 
33.709335, 33.37793, 33.794556, 34.06916, 34.561543, 34.731983, 
35.319054, 35.139149, 35.290649, 35.442154, 35.139149, 35.593655, 
34.902424, 35.356934, 35.148617, 35.868252, 35.546307, 36.739395, 
36.152321, 35.470562, 35.659939, 35.356934, 34.85508, 34.898132, 
34.859859, 35.012924, 34.553741, 34.764198, 33.463173, 33.635368, 
32.372612, 32.525665, 33.319679, 34.008457, 34.084988, 34.113686, 
35.357315, 36.141758, 36.313953, 37.366253, 38.562046, 38.542919, 
37.146229, 37.624546, 37.71064, 38.475952, 38.332451, 38.992538, 
39.260391, 39.116898, 37.997635, 37.232327, 36.141758, 34.9077, 
35.500813, 35.912163, 35.615608, 34.917259, 35.46254, 35.596478, 
35.051189, 34.725933, 34.649403, 34.391109, 34.343281, 32.525665, 
33.233582, 33.444038, 33.577969, 33.06139, 33.300545, 34.113686, 
33.654503, 32.774391, 33.003986, 32.439568, 32.183231, 32.318657, 
31.651194, 32.415386, 33.121548, 33.247292, 33.208603, 33.51815, 
33.914757, 33.943775, 33.421413, 33.759983, 33.508476, 33.431091, 
33.837368, 33.769657, 34.833725, 35.443142, 34.146915, 34.040508, 
34.514507, 34.427444, 34.659607, 34.514507, 34.021156, 35.075558, 
34.843399, 34.582218, 34.292019, 34.475811, 34.92078, 35.433472, 
35.201309, 35.404449, 34.688625, 34.572548, 33.711617, 33.160236, 
35.288372, 34.524178, 34.408096, 34.727318, 34.417774, 34.050182, 
34.611237, 33.701942, 33.86639, 32.212246, 32.308979, 32.270287, 
33.227947, 32.734612, 32.067146, 32.686241, 30.809612, 30.316271, 
31.206217, 31.49642, 30.838631, 31.022425, 30.92569, 29.716522, 
29.88097, 29.397303, 29.803583, 30.383986, 30.857977, 30.016397, 
30.451698, 31.515768, 31.486744, 33.276314, 34.233978, 34.533848, 
34.872417, 35.462494, 35.320778, 34.128433, 33.845005, 34.001381, 
34.470497, 34.607327, 33.248837, 34.245716, 34.421635, 34.900524, 
35.154633, 34.705059, 34.020927, 34.275032, 34.56823, 33.336796, 
32.418102, 32.506058, 33.033817, 34.304352, 34.411861, 35.604202, 
35.731258, 35.868084, 35.741028, 36.239471, 39.132374, 38.663254, 
37.871616, 38.497108, 39.435345, 39.562401, 39.220333, 38.027985, 
38.438469, 37.969349, 38.555748, 37.666374, 38.360283, 38.497108, 
37.646828, 37.490456, 36.952927, 36.816093, 37.119068, 36.698818, 
36.024456, 34.714832, 34.959164, 35.643299, 36.288338, 36.327427, 
36.131962, 35.55534, 35.47715, 35.095993, 35.154633, 35.066673, 
36.073326, 35.88763, 36.346977, 36.718361, 37.38295, 36.864769, 
36.430485, 36.943729, 37.318794, 36.874641, 36.943729, 37.427364, 
37.397755, 37.348404, 37.269444, 37.062172), index = structure(c(1472688000, 
1472774400, 1473120000, 1473206400, 1473292800, 1473379200, 1473638400, 
1473724800, 1473811200, 1473897600, 1473984000, 1474243200, 1474329600, 
1474416000, 1474502400, 1474588800, 1474848000, 1474934400, 1475020800, 
1475107200, 1475193600, 1475452800, 1475539200, 1475625600, 1475712000, 
1475798400, 1476057600, 1476144000, 1476230400, 1476316800, 1476403200, 
1476662400, 1476748800, 1476835200, 1476921600, 1477008000, 1477267200, 
1477353600, 1477440000, 1477526400, 1477612800, 1477872000, 1477958400, 
1478044800, 1478131200, 1478217600, 1478476800, 1478563200, 1478649600, 
1478736000, 1478822400, 1479081600, 1479168000, 1479254400, 1479340800, 
1479427200, 1479686400, 1479772800, 1479859200, 1480032000, 1480291200, 
1480377600, 1480464000, 1480550400, 1480636800, 1480896000, 1480982400, 
1481068800, 1481155200, 1481241600, 1481500800, 1481587200, 1481673600, 
1481760000, 1481846400, 1482105600, 1482192000, 1482278400, 1482364800, 
1482451200, 1482796800, 1482883200, 1482969600, 1483056000, 1483401600, 
1483488000, 1483574400, 1483660800, 1483920000, 1484006400, 1484092800, 
1484179200, 1484265600, 1484611200, 1484697600, 1484784000, 1484870400, 
1485129600, 1485216000, 1485302400, 1485388800, 1485475200, 1485734400, 
1485820800, 1485907200, 1485993600, 1486080000, 1486339200, 1486425600, 
1486512000, 1486598400, 1486684800, 1486944000, 1487030400, 1487116800, 
1487203200, 1487289600, 1487635200, 1487721600, 1487808000, 1487894400, 
1488153600, 1488240000, 1488326400, 1488412800, 1488499200, 1488758400, 
1488844800, 1488931200, 1489017600, 1489104000, 1489363200, 1489449600, 
1489536000, 1489622400, 1489708800, 1489968000, 1490054400, 1490140800, 
1490227200, 1490313600, 1490572800, 1490659200, 1490745600, 1490832000, 
1490918400, 1491177600, 1491264000, 1491350400, 1491436800, 1491523200, 
1491782400, 1491868800, 1491955200, 1492041600, 1492387200, 1492473600, 
1492560000, 1492646400, 1492732800, 1492992000, 1493078400, 1493164800, 
1493251200, 1493337600, 1493596800, 1493683200, 1493769600, 1493856000, 
1493942400, 1494201600, 1494288000, 1494374400, 1494460800, 1494547200, 
1494806400, 1494892800, 1494979200, 1495065600, 1495152000, 1495411200, 
1495497600, 1495584000, 1495670400, 1495756800, 1496102400, 1496188800, 
1496275200, 1496361600, 1496620800, 1496707200, 1496793600, 1496880000, 
1496966400, 1497225600, 1497312000, 1497398400, 1497484800, 1497571200, 
1497830400, 1497916800, 1498003200, 1498089600, 1498176000, 1498435200, 
1498521600, 1498608000, 1498694400, 1498780800, 1499040000, 1499212800, 
1499299200, 1499385600, 1499644800, 1499731200, 1499817600, 1499904000, 
1499990400, 1500249600, 1500336000, 1500422400, 1500508800, 1500595200, 
1500854400, 1500940800, 1501027200, 1501113600, 1501200000, 1501459200, 
1501545600, 1501632000, 1501718400, 1501804800, 1502064000, 1502150400, 
1502236800, 1502323200, 1502409600, 1502668800, 1502755200, 1502841600, 
1502928000, 1503014400, 1503273600, 1503360000, 1503446400, 1503532800, 
1503619200, 1503878400, 1503964800, 1504051200, 1504137600, 1504224000, 
1504569600, 1504656000, 1504742400, 1504828800, 1505088000, 1505174400, 
1505260800, 1505347200, 1505433600, 1505692800, 1505779200, 1505865600, 
1505952000, 1506038400, 1506297600, 1506384000, 1506470400, 1506556800, 
1506643200, 1506902400, 1506988800, 1507075200, 1507161600, 1507248000, 
1507507200, 1507593600, 1507680000, 1507766400, 1507852800, 1508112000, 
1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 1508457600, 1508716800, 1508803200, 
1508889600, 1508976000, 1509062400, 1509321600, 1509408000, 1509494400, 
1509580800, 1509667200, 1509926400, 1510012800, 1510099200, 1510185600, 
1510272000, 1510531200, 1510617600, 1510704000, 1510790400, 1510876800, 
1511136000, 1511222400, 1511308800, 1511481600, 1511740800, 1511827200, 
1511913600, 1512000000, 1512086400, 1512345600, 1512432000, 1512518400, 
1512604800, 1512691200, 1512950400, 1513036800, 1513123200, 1513209600, 
1513296000, 1513555200, 1513641600, 1513728000, 1513814400, 1513900800, 
1514246400, 1514332800, 1514419200, 1514505600, 1514851200, 1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516579200, 
1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517184000, 1517270400, 
1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 
1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 
1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 
1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 
1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 
1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 
1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 
1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 
1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 
1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 
1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400, 1530489600, 1530576000, 1530748800, 
1530835200, 1531094400, 1531180800, 1531267200, 1531353600, 1531440000, 
1531699200, 1531785600, 1531872000, 1531958400, 1532044800, 1532304000, 
1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 1532649600, 1532908800, 1532995200, 
1533081600, 1533168000, 1533254400, 1533513600, 1533600000, 1533686400, 
1533772800, 1533859200, 1534118400, 1534204800, 1534291200, 1534377600, 
1534464000, 1534723200, 1534809600, 1534896000, 1534982400, 1535068800, 
1535328000, 1535414400, 1535500800, 1535587200, 1535673600, 1536019200, 
1536105600, 1536192000, 1536278400, 1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 
1536796800, 1536883200, 1537142400, 1537228800, 1537315200, 1537401600, 
1537488000, 1537747200, 1537833600, 1537920000, 1538006400, 1538092800, 
1538352000, 1538438400, 1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 1538956800, 
1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 1539302400, 1539561600, 1539648000, 
1539734400, 1539820800, 1539907200, 1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 
1540425600, 1540512000, 1540771200, 1540857600, 1540944000, 1541030400, 
1541116800, 1541376000, 1541462400, 1541548800, 1541635200, 1541721600, 
1541980800, 1542067200, 1542153600, 1542240000, 1542326400, 1542585600, 
1542672000, 1542758400, 1542931200, 1543190400, 1543276800, 1543363200, 
1543449600, 1543536000, 1543795200, 1543881600, 1544054400, 1544140800, 
1544400000, 1544486400, 1544572800, 1544659200, 1544745600, 1545004800, 
1545091200, 1545177600, 1545264000, 1545350400, 1545609600, 1545782400, 
1545868800, 1545955200, 1546214400, 1546387200, 1546473600, 1546560000, 
1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 1547164800, 1547424000, 
1547510400, 1547596800, 1547683200, 1547769600, 1548115200, 1548201600, 
1548288000, 1548374400, 1548633600, 1548720000, 1548806400, 1548892800, 
1548979200, 1549238400, 1549324800, 1549411200, 1549497600, 1549584000, 
1549843200, 1549929600, 1550016000, 1550102400, 1550188800, 1550534400, 
1550620800, 1550707200, 1550793600, 1551052800, 1551139200, 1551225600, 
1551312000, 1551398400, 1551657600, 1551744000, 1551830400, 1551916800, 
1552003200, 1552262400, 1552348800, 1552435200, 1552521600, 1552608000, 
1552867200, 1552953600, 1553040000, 1553126400, 1553212800, 1553472000, 
1553558400, 1553644800, 1553731200, 1553817600, 1554076800, 1554163200, 
1554249600, 1554336000, 1554422400, 1554681600, 1554768000, 1554854400, 
1554940800, 1555027200, 1555286400, 1555372800, 1555459200, 1555545600, 
1555891200, 1555977600, 1556064000, 1556150400, 1556236800, 1556496000, 
1556582400, 1556668800, 1556755200, 1556841600, 1557100800, 1557187200, 
1557273600, 1557360000, 1557446400, 1557705600, 1557792000, 1557878400, 
1557964800, 1558051200, 1558310400, 1558396800, 1558483200, 1558569600, 
1558656000, 1559001600, 1559088000, 1559174400, 1559260800, 1559520000, 
1559606400, 1559692800, 1559779200, 1559865600, 1560124800, 1560211200, 
1560297600, 1560384000, 1560470400, 1560729600, 1560816000, 1560902400, 
1560988800, 1561075200, 1561334400, 1561420800, 1561507200, 1561593600, 
1561680000, 1561939200, 1562025600, 1562112000, 1562284800, 1562544000, 
1562630400, 1562716800, 1562803200, 1562889600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563408000, 1563494400, 1563753600, 1563840000, 1563926400, 
1564012800, 1564099200, 1564358400, 1564444800, 1564531200, 1564617600, 
1564704000, 1564963200, 1565049600, 1565136000, 1565222400, 1565308800, 
1565568000, 1565654400, 1565740800, 1565827200, 1565913600, 1566172800, 
1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566777600, 1566864000, 
1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 
1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 
1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 
1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 
1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 
1570665600, 1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 
1571356800, 1571616000, 1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 
1572220800, 1572307200, 1572393600, 1572480000, 1572566400, 1572825600, 
1572912000, 1572998400, 1573084800, 1573171200, 1573430400, 1573516800, 
1573603200, 1573689600, 1573776000, 1574035200, 1574121600, 1574208000, 
1574294400, 1574380800, 1574640000, 1574726400, 1574812800, 1574985600, 
1575244800, 1575331200, 1575417600, 1575504000, 1575590400, 1575849600, 
1575936000, 1576022400, 1576108800, 1576195200, 1576454400, 1576540800, 
1576627200, 1576713600, 1576800000, 1577059200, 1577145600, 1577318400, 
1577404800, 1577664000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1585412559.29406, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(837L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Y1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used in rollapply must produce an ordinary vector.  An `lm` object is not an acceptable output.

Also by default it just passes the coredata of the object into the function but if you want a zoo object passed so that you can get its time then use `coredata = FALSE`.

`lm` may have problems with the zoo object passed so use its coredata.

In lmFunction shown in the question it is trying to use lm(..., x) as if x were a data frame but x is not a data frame.

The two examples below return fitted values and coefficients respectively.

Plotting a line for each time point is going to look like a real mess with all those lines but we show how to produce it anyways at the end.

```
library(xts)

Y1 <- as.zoo(data)$Y1

fitfun <- function(x) fitted(lm(coredata(x) ~ time(x)))
r1 <- rollapplyr(Y1, 40, fitfun, coredata = FALSE, fill = NA)
dim(r1)
## [1] 837  40

coeffun <- function(x) coef(lm(coredata(x) ~ time(x)))
r2 <- rollapplyr(Y1, 40, coeffun, coredata = FALSE, fill = NA)
dim(r2)
## [1] 837  2

# plot
r2na <- na.omit(r2)
plot(Y1)
junk <- Map(abline, a = r2na[, 1], b = r2na[, 2])
```